Potential of rotation in 41-1 of The Feynman Lectures on Physics
The picture below is from  41-1 of  The Feynman Lectures on Physics. First, in
$$
V=\frac{\alpha \theta^2}{2}   \tag{1}
$$
I think the $\alpha$ should be analogue of elastic coefficient in Hooke's theorem ($F=-kx$).  But Feynman do not say how to calculate the $\alpha$. So, I don't know how to get
$$
V=\frac{I \omega_0^2 \theta^2}{2}.    \tag{2}
$$
Namely, how to show $\alpha = I \omega_0^2$ ?
Maybe, Feynman said something about it, but I forgot. If so,  telling me in which section  is enough. Thanks.




$\alpha$ has units of energy, so probably there's a lot more to Hooke's theorem.

I think it is quite trivial if you consider the derivative of the potential as the torque over the body and write the equation of motion in terms of torque and moment inertia

The kinetic energy is $~T_c=\frac 12 ,I,\omega^2~$, thus
for $~\omega(t)=\omega_0,\cos(\frac {2,\pi}{T},t)~$ the average of the kinetic energy is $\frac 1T,\int_{-T}^T,T_c(t),dt=\frac 12 ,I,\omega_0^2$

Derivation of (1) is relatively easy, Hooke's law for "rotational spring": $ \tau = -\alpha \theta $. Multiplying both sides by $d \theta$ and integrating, we get $\int \tau d \theta = -\alpha \int \theta d \theta$. So we get $W=-V=-1/2 \alpha \theta ^ 2 $.

@Eli  As your say about $T_c, \omega(t)$, I calculate $\int_{-T}^T T_c(t) dt =0$.

@AgniusVasiliauskas  Thanks. $\tau$ is torque
?  And do you know how to get   $\alpha = I \omega_0^2$ ?

@EnhaoLan you should take $\omega ^2$ for the average, the result is correct

@EnhaoLan Yes, torque. At the moment - no, I'm not sure how to prove $\alpha$ coefficient being related to an average natural frequency kinetic energy.
